# How to define a database trigger in sqlite using sqlalchemy/python?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to define and build out a sqlite database; it has 2 related tables called Authors and Books.  There is a column in both that flags a record as favorite; I'm trying to build in a trigger so that if authors.favorite is updated, it will then go into the Books table, find every book with that same author (they are joined by an author id) and then update books.favorite for that record with the same value.  So if I say an author is a favorite, all their books are also marked favorite.  If I un-favorite them, those books are all un-favorited.

I've seen some things about listeners, auto creating timestamps, etc, but I can't find any documentation about building a trigger so that when one table is updated, it goes out and updates a different table.  Can anyone point me toward some resources?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to just define the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_favorites
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON AUTHOR

BEGIN

UPDATE BOOKS
SET favorite = new.favorite
WHERE author_id = new.author_id;

END;
```